# Adding directive dynamically using ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am working on a modal for a client. I have created a directive that works great, the problem is that one modal is made ahead each time it is used like..

**What I have**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{item.id}}">Click</a>
  <my-dialog element-id="item.id">
    <h1>This is the body of the modal</h1>
  </my-dialog>
</div>
```

This works great for a small amount of modals but we are using a very large number of modals. So I would like to add the directive at runtime, something closer to...

**What I want...**

```
<div id="warning"></div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="{{item.id}}" ng-click="showModal(item)">Click</a>
</div>
...
// inside controller
$scope.showModal = function(item){
  $http.get('/someUrl').success(function(data){
    var result = $compile('<my-dialog element-id="'+item.id+'">'+data+'</my-dialog>').($scope);
    $("#warning").append(result);
  });
}
$scope.hideModal = function(){
  $( "#warning" ).empty();
}
```

This of course isn't working yet. Also it doesn't feel like the best way. This would allow me to remove the directive once it has been closed.

Please include a plunker or equivalent for the check.

Comment: Do you see any error in console? seems like a syntax error here `$compile('<my-dialog element-id="'+item.id+'">'+data+'</my-dialog>')($scope);`

Comment: Right that is part of the problem I have no idea where to get it from.

Comment: it must be data.data... do a console log of data and inject $ compile in your directive

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do this is to use ng-repeat with your items, then call $scope.$apply() after you push a new item to the list.  The HTML could look like this ...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  <span dialog>
    <a class="dialog-anchor">{{item.name}}</a>
    <div class="dialog-body">{{item.id}}</div>
  </span>
</div>
```

... and the directive like this

```
.directive('dialog', [function () {
    return {
    scope: {
    id: '@elementId',
  }
  , link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
    var body = $(el).find('.dialog-body').detach();
    $(el).find('.dialog-anchor').on('click', function () {
      $('body').append(body);
    });
  }};
  }])
```

... and the controller like this

```
.controller('app', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    {name: 'first', id: 001},
    {name: 'second', id: 002}
  ];

  setTimeout(function () {
    $scope.items.push({name: 'three', id: 003});
    if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
  }, 2000);  
}])
```

Here's the plunker... http://plnkr.co/edit/2ETbeCKGcHW3CJCfD9d7?p=preview.  You can see the $scope.$apply call in the setTimeout where I push a new item to the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var result = $compile('<my-dialog element-id="'+item.id+'">'+data+'</my-dialog>')($scope);
```

Comment: Where does compile come from? can you show me a plunker?